# XML dataset transformation

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, dataset

Hi I am new to XSLT i want to transform the Xml Dataset  where student name is mapped from a xml where there is a dataset of student name and roll no. classwise.

I want to use a xslt but i dont want to add all the tags just the column name tag which is to be mapped and rest other columns as it is.

here is the input and output dataset example.
The xml is normal dataset.writexml from c# code.

Table1:

```
RollNo    Sub1  Sub2 Sub3 Sub4
1         65    89   67   34
2         67    86   67   76
3         86    67   78   45
4         56    56   87   56
5         76    56   56   78
```

Table2

```
Name      Sub1  Sub2 Sub3 Sub4
Aman      65    89   67   34
Ankit     67    86   67   76
Om        86    67   78   45
Narendra  56    56   87   56
Faisal    76    56   56   78
```

This is the Xml to be used for transformation

**Mapping XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<School>
    <Class Name="Class1">
        <StudentData Name="Aman" RollNo="1"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Ankit" RollNo="2"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Om" RollNo="3"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Narendra" RollNo="4"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Faisal" RollNo="5"  />    
    </Class>
    <Class Name="Class2">
        <StudentData Name="Abhinav" RollNo="1"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Abhishek" RollNo="2"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Ishaan" RollNo="3"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Mayank" RollNo="4"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Bhavana" RollNo="5"  />    
    </Class>
</School>
```

XSLT created so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
             xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="http://www.contoso.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DocumentElement>
      <xsl:for-each select="//Comparision">
        <xsl:if test ="number(COL7)">
      <PositionMaster>

                    <xsl:variable name="RollNo" select="normalize-space(COL1)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="Name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="document('../../../MappingFiles/Mapping.xml')/School/PB[@Name='Class1']/TagData[@RollNo=$RollNo]/@Name"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$Name!=''">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$Name"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$Name"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </Name>
          </PositionMaster>
        </xsl:if >
      </xsl:for-each>
    </DocumentElement>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks
Aman

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: **1.** Please post your input and output as XML code. --  ** 2.** How will the transformation know which `Class` in the mapping XML to use for the lookup?

Comment: @michael.hor257k xslt will have the class name hardcoded in it.

Comment: @king.code so far i have created the xslt attached .
This xslt only gives the columns i mapped.

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish A bounty is no substitute for adding the XML input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as an example, given the following **input XML**:

```
<Table>
    <Student>
        <RollNo>1</RollNo>
        <Sub1>11</Sub1>
        <Sub2>12</Sub2>
        <Sub3>13</Sub3>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <RollNo>2</RollNo>
        <Sub1>21</Sub1>
        <Sub2>22</Sub2>
        <Sub3>23</Sub3>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <RollNo>3</RollNo>
        <Sub1>31</Sub1>
        <Sub2>32</Sub2>
        <Sub3>33</Sub3>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <RollNo>4</RollNo>
        <Sub1>41</Sub1>
        <Sub2>42</Sub2>
        <Sub3>43</Sub3>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <RollNo>5</RollNo>
        <Sub1>51</Sub1>
        <Sub2>52</Sub2>
        <Sub3>53</Sub3>
    </Student>
</Table>
```

and an external file named "Mapping.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<School>
    <Class Name="Class1">
        <StudentData Name="Aman" RollNo="1"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Ankit" RollNo="2"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Om" RollNo="3"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Narendra" RollNo="4"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Faisal" RollNo="5"  />    
    </Class>
    <Class Name="Class2">
        <StudentData Name="Abhinav" RollNo="1"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Abhishek" RollNo="2"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Ishaan" RollNo="3"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Mayank" RollNo="4"  />   
        <StudentData Name="Bhavana" RollNo="5"  />    
    </Class>
</School>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="class">Class2</xsl:param>

<xsl:key name="student" match="StudentData" use="concat(@RollNo, '|' , ../@Name)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RollNo">
    <Name>
        <xsl:variable name="RollNo" select="." />
        <!-- switch context to the other document in order to use key -->
        <xsl:for-each select="document('Mapping.xml')">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('student', concat($RollNo, '|' , $class))/@Name" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Name>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Table>
   <Student>
      <Name>Abhinav</Name>
      <Sub1>11</Sub1>
      <Sub2>12</Sub2>
      <Sub3>13</Sub3>
   </Student>
   <Student>
      <Name>Abhishek</Name>
      <Sub1>21</Sub1>
      <Sub2>22</Sub2>
      <Sub3>23</Sub3>
   </Student>
   <Student>
      <Name>Ishaan</Name>
      <Sub1>31</Sub1>
      <Sub2>32</Sub2>
      <Sub3>33</Sub3>
   </Student>
   <Student>
      <Name>Mayank</Name>
      <Sub1>41</Sub1>
      <Sub2>42</Sub2>
      <Sub3>43</Sub3>
   </Student>
   <Student>
      <Name>Bhavana</Name>
      <Sub1>51</Sub1>
      <Sub2>52</Sub2>
      <Sub3>53</Sub3>
   </Student>
</Table>
```